# GNU Rush invalid uid

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, chroot

I'm trying to configure Rush for limited shell and scp access to a server I have. I am using Rush 2.3, fresh compiled. And the default config they have in their docs. Still, everytime I try to run a test I get `invalid uid`, even though the user has CHRoot programs in its directory, and permissions to run them, and a shell file.

Here is my config:

```
rush 2.0

global
  debug 3

rule default
  limits t10r20
  umask 002
  clrenv
  keepenv USER LOGNAME HOME PATH
  setenv PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/bin"
  fall-through

rule scp-to
  match $command ~ "^scp (-v )?-t"
  set [0] = "/bin/scp"
  chroot "~"
  chdir "/"

rule scp-from
  match $command ~ "^scp (-v )?-f"
  set [0] = "/bin/scp"
  chroot "~"                       
  chdir "/"
  
rule git
  match $command ~ "^git-(receive|upload)-pack"
  match $1 ~ "^/vcs-roots/git/[^ ]+\\.git$"
  set command =~ "s|^|/usr/bin/|"
  
rule git-trap
  match $command ~ "^git-(receive|upload)-pack"
  exit "fatal: access to this repository is denied."
  
rule sftp
  match $program ~ "^.*/sftp-server"
  set [0] = "bin/sftp-server"
  umask 002
  chroot "~"
  chdir "/"

rule login
  interactive true
  chroot "~"
  chdir "/"
  map program /etc/rush.shell : ${user} 1 2

rule nologin
  interactive true
  exit "You don't have interactive access to this machine."
```

When I run interactive: `# /usr/local/sbin/rush --user=myuser --test -i`

It just tells me invalid uid, even though the UID and user exist fine. If I login as the user `su myuser` with SH as its shell, it works fine. Debug Log:

```
rush: Debug: Command line:
rush: Debug:    0: /usr/local/sbin/rush
rush: Debug:    1: --user=myuser
rush: Debug:    2: --test
rush: Debug:    3: -i
rush: Debug: Environment:
rush: Debug:    0 SHELL=/bin/bash
rush: Debug:    1 PWD=/zpool2/myuser
rush: Debug:    2 LOGNAME=root
rush: Debug:    3 XDG_SESSION_TYPE=tty
rush: Debug:    4 LS_OPTIONS=--color=tty -F -a -b -T 0
rush: Debug:    5 MOTD_SHOWN=pam
rush: Debug:    6 HOME=/root
rush: Debug:    7 LANG=en_US.UTF-8
rush: Debug:    8 LS_COLORS=rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.wim=01;31:*.swm=01;31:*.dwm=01;31:*.esd=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.webp=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:
rush: Debug:    9 SSH_CONNECTION=0.0.0.0 60777 0.0.0.0 22
rush: Debug:   10 XDG_SESSION_CLASS=user
rush: Debug:   11 TERM=xterm
rush: Debug:   12 USER=root
rush: Debug:   13 SHLVL=1
rush: Debug:   14 XDG_SESSION_ID=845160
rush: Debug:   15 XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/0
rush: Debug:   16 PS1=[\u@\h:\w]$ 
rush: Debug:   17 SSH_CLIENT=0.0.0.0 60777 22
rush: Debug:   18 XDG_DATA_DIRS=/usr/local/share:/usr/share:/var/lib/snapd/desktop
rush: Debug:   19 PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/root/bin
rush: Debug:   20 DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/0/bus
rush: Debug:   21 SSH_TTY=/dev/pts/2
rush: Debug:   22 _=/usr/local/sbin/rush
rush: Debug:   23 OLDPWD=/zpool2/myuser/bin
rush: Notice: Serving interactive shell request for myuser by rule login
rush: Debug: Rule login at /usr/local/etc/rush.rc:54 matched
rush: Debug: Final environment:
rush: Debug:    0: SHELL=/bin/bash
rush: Debug:    1: PWD=/zpool2/myuser
rush: Debug:    2: LOGNAME=root
rush: Debug:    3: XDG_SESSION_TYPE=tty
rush: Debug:    4: LS_OPTIONS=--color=tty -F -a -b -T 0
rush: Debug:    5: MOTD_SHOWN=pam
rush: Debug:    6: HOME=/root
rush: Debug:    7: LANG=en_US.UTF-8
rush: Debug:    8: LS_COLORS=rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.wim=01;31:*.swm=01;31:*.dwm=01;31:*.esd=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.webp=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:
rush: Debug:    9: SSH_CONNECTION=0.0.0.0 60777 45.135.163.234 22
rush: Debug:   10: XDG_SESSION_CLASS=user
rush: Debug:   11: TERM=xterm
rush: Debug:   12: USER=root
rush: Debug:   13: SHLVL=1
rush: Debug:   14: XDG_SESSION_ID=845160
rush: Debug:   15: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/0
rush: Debug:   16: PS1=[\u@\h:\w]$ 
rush: Debug:   17: SSH_CLIENT=0.0.0.0 60777 22
rush: Debug:   18: XDG_DATA_DIRS=/usr/local/share:/usr/share:/var/lib/snapd/desktop
rush: Debug:   19: PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/root/bin
rush: Debug:   20: DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/0/bus
rush: Debug:   21: SSH_TTY=/dev/pts/2
rush: Debug:   22: _=/usr/local/sbin/rush
rush: Debug:   23: OLDPWD=/zpool2/myuser/bin
rush: Debug: Transforming program name (/bin/sh)
rush: Debug: Transformation map: /etc/rush.shell, :, ${user}, 1, 2, (null)
rush: Debug: transformed value: /bin/sh
rush: Debug: Program name: /bin/sh
rush: Debug: Final arguments:
rush: Debug:    0: /bin/sh
rush: Debug: Chroot dir: /zpool2/myuser
rush: Debug: Home dir: /
rush: Error: invalid uid 1019
```

I copied all binaries being used and libraries into the users directory and gave them ownership. Also, if I run `chroot /zpool2/myuser /bin/sh` works perfectly fine and keeps me jailed to that users directory. So I'm at a loss why rush won't do it. If I remove `chroot` from rush's rc file, it works, but then the user is not jailed.

Comment: I never used rush so this might be a silly dumb question but... what's the ownership of `/zpool2/myuser` ? Shouldn't it be owned by 1019 ? Also, isn't `/zpool2/myuser` the `~` `$HOME` folder of user `myuser` in the system?

Comment: fwiw: I faced similar issue with my setup i am using rush with ssh so i had forgotten to copy passwd,shadow and group file to the chroot location. after copying from /etc to etc inside the chroot it started working as now it knows who the user is

Comment: That was it @MohsinKhan thank you! If you want to post that as the answer I will accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The <kbd>$</kbd>  prompt in `$ /usr/local/sbin/rush --user=myuser...` suggest that you're running the command as an unprivileged user.

The [`--user=` option](https://www.gnu.org.ua/software/rush/manual/rush.html#Option-Summary) has several restrictions:

> This option implies `--test` and is **valid only when used by root** and **in conjunction** with the `-c` option.

and when you're not running the command as root that is possibly what triggers the invalid uid error message.

Comment: That's my fault, I copied the command then put a $ in front for the post. I am running the command as root.

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue when using rush with ssh.

you need to copy `passwd`,`shadow` and `groups` file to the chroot location. after copying from `/etc` to etc inside the chroot location like `your chroot loc/etc/`, it will resolve the users now.

Prior to it there is no way to know who the user is once ssh happen and the chroot is applied